# Spring Integration KafkaProducerMessageHandler TimeoutException on metadata sending

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I'm trying to achieve the following scenario with Spring Integration and Kafka on Docker:

- Poll HTTP endpoint, result in String
- Send result to Kafka

The polling works fine, and my application setup seems to be correct, because the app is starting without any connection exceptions.

As you can see in the output, the KafkaProducerMessageHandler receives the message, but hangs with 'Trying to send metadata request to node -1' for over a minute, then throws a TimeoutException.

Here is the output and code, needed to link:

[OUTPUT](https://github.com/markuslamm/spring-kafka-test/blob/master/spring-kafka-test.log)

[kafka-broker.log](https://github.com/markuslamm/spring-kafka-test/blob/master/kafka_broker.log)

[zookeeper.log](https://github.com/markuslamm/spring-kafka-test/blob/master/zookeeper.log)

Here my application setup:

[docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/markuslamm/spring-kafka-test/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

[application.yml](https://github.com/markuslamm/spring-kafka-test/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml)

[KafkaIntegration.java](https://github.com/markuslamm/spring-kafka-test/blob/master/src/main/java/net/twentyfourseven/springkafka/config/KafkaIntegration.java)

The KafkaConfig ist based and the Kafka example from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples and the Kafka Docker container from https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker.

Thanks for any ideas and suggestions!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stupid!

My docker-compose was:

```
kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
        - "9092:9092"
    links:
        - zookeeper:zk
    environment:
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.59.103
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

where 192.168.59.103 is my IP. I had to change it to localhost, now it seems fine.

```
17:25:26.797 DEBUG 25436 --- [ask-scheduler-9] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'kafkaChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload={"login":"markuslamm","id":1075906,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1075906?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm","html_url":"https://github.com/markuslamm","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false,"name":"Markus Lamm","company":null,"blog":null,"location":null,"email":null,"hireable":null,"bio":null,"public_repos":21,"public_gists":0,"followers":0,"following":0,"created_at":"2011-09-24T07:04:34Z","updated_at":"2016-01-26T15:19:00Z"}, headers={Server=GitHub.com, Cache-Control=public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60, ETag="c06cdef5b902bb019cced50412d4b913", Vary=[Accept, Accept-Encoding], Last-Modified=1453821540000, id=6bffbe99-0e6d-55a5-65a1-208c7be7542d, Content-Length=1135, contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8, http_statusCode=200, Date=1453825526000, timestamp=1453825526797}]
2016-01-26 17:25:26.797 DEBUG 25436 --- [ask-scheduler-9] ssor$ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper : kafkaIntegration.kafkaHandler.serviceActivator.handler received message: GenericMessage [payload={"login":"markuslamm","id":1075906,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1075906?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm","html_url":"https://github.com/markuslamm","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false,"name":"Markus Lamm","company":null,"blog":null,"location":null,"email":null,"hireable":null,"bio":null,"public_repos":21,"public_gists":0,"followers":0,"following":0,"created_at":"2011-09-24T07:04:34Z","updated_at":"2016-01-26T15:19:00Z"}, headers={Server=GitHub.com, Cache-Control=public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60, ETag="c06cdef5b902bb019cced50412d4b913", Vary=[Accept, Accept-Encoding], Last-Modified=1453821540000, id=6bffbe99-0e6d-55a5-65a1-208c7be7542d, Content-Length=1135, contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8, http_statusCode=200, Date=1453825526000, timestamp=1453825526797}]
2016-01-26 17:25:26.797 DEBUG 25436 --- [ask-scheduler-9] o.s.i.k.o.KafkaProducerMessageHandler    : kafkaHandler received message: GenericMessage [payload={"login":"markuslamm","id":1075906,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1075906?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm","html_url":"https://github.com/markuslamm","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false,"name":"Markus Lamm","company":null,"blog":null,"location":null,"email":null,"hireable":null,"bio":null,"public_repos":21,"public_gists":0,"followers":0,"following":0,"created_at":"2011-09-24T07:04:34Z","updated_at":"2016-01-26T15:19:00Z"}, headers={Server=GitHub.com, Cache-Control=public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60, ETag="c06cdef5b902bb019cced50412d4b913", Vary=[Accept, Accept-Encoding], Last-Modified=1453821540000, id=6bffbe99-0e6d-55a5-65a1-208c7be7542d, Content-Length=1135, contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8, http_statusCode=200, Date=1453825526000, timestamp=1453825526797}]
2016-01-26 17:25:26.798 DEBUG 25436 --- [ask-scheduler-9] ssor$ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper : handler 'kafkaIntegration.kafkaHandler.serviceActivator.handler' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload={"login":"markuslamm","id":1075906,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1075906?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm","html_url":"https://github.com/markuslamm","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false,"name":"Markus Lamm","company":null,"blog":null,"location":null,"email":null,"hireable":null,"bio":null,"public_repos":21,"public_gists":0,"followers":0,"following":0,"created_at":"2011-09-24T07:04:34Z","updated_at":"2016-01-26T15:19:00Z"}, headers={Server=GitHub.com, Cache-Control=public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60, ETag="c06cdef5b902bb019cced50412d4b913", Vary=[Accept, Accept-Encoding], Last-Modified=1453821540000, id=6bffbe99-0e6d-55a5-65a1-208c7be7542d, Content-Length=1135, contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8, http_statusCode=200, Date=1453825526000, timestamp=1453825526797}]
2016-01-26 17:25:26.798 DEBUG 25436 --- [ask-scheduler-9] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'kafkaChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload={"login":"markuslamm","id":1075906,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1075906?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm","html_url":"https://github.com/markuslamm","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/markuslamm/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false,"name":"Markus Lamm","company":null,"blog":null,"location":null,"email":null,"hireable":null,"bio":null,"public_repos":21,"public_gists":0,"followers":0,"following":0,"created_at":"2011-09-24T07:04:34Z","updated_at":"2016-01-26T15:19:00Z"}, headers={Server=GitHub.com, Cache-Control=public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60, ETag="c06cdef5b902bb019cced50412d4b913", Vary=[Accept, Accept-Encoding], Last-Modified=1453821540000, id=6bffbe99-0e6d-55a5-65a1-208c7be7542d, Content-Length=1135, contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8, http_statusCode=200, Date=1453825526000, timestamp=1453825526797}]
2016-01-26 17:25:26.799 DEBUG 25436 --- [ask-scheduler-9] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'httpPollChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=, headers={id=55aecfc4-ea57-d769-4275-801b39a0416d, timestamp=1453825526420}]
```

Comment: That's cool! You even can accept your own answer to close the discussion. Sorry, I'm not familiar with Docket, so can't help there.

Comment: Have to wait 2 days, SO says..;)

Answer (score 1):

We see something like this in your logs:

```
227 --- [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Sending metadata request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, payload=null, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=3,api_version=0,correlation_id=23,client_id=producer-1}, body={topics=[test.topic]})) to node -1
2016-01-26 15:22:24.986 DEBUG 4227 --- [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Trying to send metadata request to node -1
```

Looks like you really should check the Broker logs.

First of all it might be :

```
kafka.common.InvalidTopicException: topic name TOPIC= is illegal, contains a character other than ASCII alphanumerics, '.', '_' and '-'
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1884

So, the `.` in your topic name is illegal. You might use incompatible Kafka version with its client. The Spring Integration Kafka 1.3 is based on the Kafka-0.8.2.2.

From other side it might be some network problem: [Kafka 0.8.2.2 - Unable to publish messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541114/kafka-0-8-2-2-unable-to-publish-messages)

Comment: Thanks for this fast reply!! I updated my answer with the broker and zookeeper logs. But I don't see something suspicious. I also removed the dot in the queue and messagekey, and use Kafka 0.8.2.2, but unfortunately the problem still exists.